# My loss remains at ~0.4 regardless of any changes

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, loss

I am quite new to CNN and ML in general, and I remain in a phase where I use it as a tool (instead of building my own network). I am using and adapting a UNET code provided here : https://github.com/AhadMomin/semantic-segmentation-digital-rock-physics, for segmentation of grayscale pictures. My images are 120x120 grayscale, and the outputs are binary segmented pictures.

This works fine, and while my validation accuracy is relatively high, my loss will (always) reach ~0.4, and this independently of :

- the dataset I am using
- the dropout values
- the learning rate
- the L2 value
- the maxNorm value
- whether or not I use batch norm
- the number of image sample I'll train the model with
- the batch size

The above represents what I've tried in tuning so far. On top of these, I have tried early stoppings (using various patience), increasing/decreasing the number of epochs, fidgeting with the filter size (from 8 to 32) and the kernel size (from 2,2 to 4,4).

Of course, the shape of my val acc and loss will change if I update these params, but in the end, it will always end up reaching a high val acc, and about 0.4 for my val loss.

[image]

I am starting to running out of ideas on how to fix that (if I get it right that's also an overfitting issue...?).

I've combed through stackoverflow in the quest of any good tip (and found some). But right now I feel like hitting a wall.

Any help would be welcomed :(

(please let me know if you need any part of my code).

EDIT: [Here is the architecture of my CNN](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yePk6aPDUq8nT2jyEpcbaKUACG41ehA4/view?usp=sharing)

I had to put it in a txt file on my drive for visualization, as the amount of character is above SO's limit :)

Comment: Hi there! can you please provide a link from your "model architecture" and/or "model training" codes so we can help you better ?

Comment: Done, sorry for the late reply :)

Comment: Maybe this post would fit better in the data science comunity

Comment: I've crossplotted. Thanks for the tip